# React Native Retrieving Image file paths from Database

Tags: image, react-native, require

I am wondering how to model an application in React Native that retrieves images from a database and displays them to the user. I am planning to store images in a directory and have a database store the file paths for all of the images.

But, a problem that I found that other people encounter is that React Native requires a completely static file path in the source code. A solution that I frequently saw was one where a single index or switch statement is made to refer to all of the images. I believe that this model, however, would not work for my application as users should be able to upload their own images, which would then be stored on the server with its file path put into the database, but would not be represented in the switch statement. What kind of solution might there be for this situation?

Comment: I save images to a database as byte array and return them from an API as a byte array. No need to deal with file locations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For my react-native app, for uploading photos, I used react-native-image-picker to choose a picture from the user's device and rns3 to send the picture to aws s3. For the file name of the picture, I used the app name, plus the moment js library to dynamically create a unique file name. You can also use a uuid as well.

For example :

```
  ImagePicker.showImagePicker(options, response => {

    if (response.didCancel) {
      // alert cancel
    } else if (response.error) {
      // alert error
    } else {
      const { uri } = response;
      const extensionIndex = uri.lastIndexOf(".");
      const extension = uri.slice(extensionIndex + 1);

      const file = {
        uri,
        name: `${YourAppName}_${moment.utc().format("YYYY-MM-DD-HH-mm-ss")}.${extension}`,
        type: "image/jpeg"
      };

      const options = {
        keyPrefix: ****,
        bucket: ****,
        region: ****,
        accessKey: ****,
        secretKey: ****
      };

      // send file to aws s3 and to your db ...

      RNS3.put(file, options)
        .progress(event => {
          console.log(`percent: ${event.percent}`);
        })
        .then(response => {
          if (response.status !== 201) {
            console.error(response.body);
            return;
          }

          // this will contain the image url
          let image = response.headers.Location;

          // send image url to your db

        })
    })
```

For displaying the images, simply use the url stored in the db.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense on the uploading side! But in terms of retrieving the image, if I were to create a variable to hold the url stored in the db and pass the variable into a source={require('my_variable')} statement, would that raise an error? Some sources and the documentation state that src resources must be static and so I am a bit lost on whether or not this would work.

Comment: You don't need to use the require statement with a url. Just do something like this:
`<Image
          style={{width: 50, height: 50}}
          source={{uri: yourImageUrl}}
        />`

with `yourImageUrl` being a variable containing your image's url

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/image

Comment: So just to clarify, would it be correct to store an image's Url on a database (in the corresponding row), and then query that Url and store it into a variable which is given to an image component?